# Ruby on rails, Save data in two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question.

I have this model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :documents
  belongs_to :course_unit
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people  
  has_one :presentation
  has_and_belongs_to_many :supervisors, :class_name => "Person", :join_table => :projects_supervisors
end
```

and this model:

```
class Presentation < ApplicationRecord                    
  belongs_to :project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :juries, :class_name => "Person", :join_table => :juries_presentations
end
```

When I create a new project, I have many attributes of the model Project and two attributes (room and date) from Presentation model, so I don't know how to send data from room and date attributes to the presentation model.

So my question is: How can I create a new project that saves data in project table and presentation table?

**UPDATE #1**

My project controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new 
end 

def edit
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  @project.build_presentation
  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully   created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update(project_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully  updated.'}
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def set_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :resume, :github, :grade,   :project_url, :date, :featured, :finished, :user_id, :course_unit_id,   presentation_attributes: [ :date , :room ])
end
```

My index view for Projects is:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :presentations do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :"Dia de Apresentação" %>
  <%= ff.date_field :date %>
  <%= ff.label :"Sala de Apresentação" %>
  <%= ff.text_area :room %>
  <% end 
  <%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
project = Project.new(name: 'project 1')
project.build_presentation(room: 'room 1', date: Time.current)
project.save
```

It will save project with name `project 1` and presentation belongs to that project, with room `room 1` and date is `Time.current`.

And you need to update your models to avoid presence validation.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :presentation, inverse_of: :project
end

class Presentation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :presentation
end
```

Comment: In project controller?

Comment: Good it works, bue now i need to be not static xD. i need to insert in view the data

Comment: So you need to use nested attributes. You can take a look at this [nested attributes tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes)

Comment: I do the nested things and then do this:

`<div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :presentation do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :"Dia de Apresentação" %>
    <%= f.date_field :date %>
    <% end %>
</div>`

Comment: You should chang `f` to `ff` of `f.fields_for`: `<div class="field"> <%= f.fields_for :presentation do |ff| %> <%= ff.label :"Dia de Apresentação" %> <%= ff.date_field :date %> <% end %> </div>`

Comment: I have already made these changes but now it gives me an error when I try to create a project: Project must exist.


The goal is to create a project and associate a presentation date with this project.

Comment: Check my updated answer, you need to add `inverse_of` to associations in your models.

Comment: I put these changes but in the index view does not appear the fields. If I go to see the database, the fields will appear null.
I am writing the fields but for the presentation table there are not those fields.

Comment: Please add your view and controller to question.

Comment: @MiguelCoelho `f.fields_for :presentations` should be `f.fields_for :presentation`, `presentation` without `s`.

Comment: But if I take out the s, the field disappears from the view

Comment: Did you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for : presentation` in `Project` model?

Comment: Add `id` in `presentation_attributes`: `presentation_attributes: [:id, :date , :room]`, in your new action, add `@project.build_presentation` and remove `@project.build_presentation` from create action.

Comment: i added the `id` in te `presentation_attributes: [:id, :date , :room]` but if i remove de `s` from de `f.fields_for :presentations` the fields in view dont show. if i put the `s`  the data still do not go to the presentations table. 
Simply these fields in the table are null

Comment: `in your new action, add @project.build_presentation and remove @project.build_presentation from create action.`